# Highcharts: How to plot Bar Chart where each series is plotted together rather than separated?

Tags: highcharts

I have two series and if I try to plot them using column chart type it will look like this

[image]

What's the code to make it plot the series like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to set your data up differently.

Instead of a series for each group, the way you want to do it, you have to set the data up as a series for each *member* of the group.

```
Example:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/yPLVP/12/

[[edit:

if you want to maintain color within the grouping, you can specify the color in the point object:

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/yPLVP/13/

{{edit again:

You could also work with multiple x axes, side by side:

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/yPLVP/14/

Or, in reality, what you are plotting is two different charts, so two different charts is a perfectly reasonable option.

Comment: Thank you. I have done something similar  but I consider it a "hack". Would love to be able to do this with two series. As in your proposed solution I need some code to break the series up and reorganised before plotting. It's unintuitive. In this solution there are actually 3 series instead of 2? Am I right?

Comment: that is correct.  see updated answer for additional options.  none are as 'built in' as you are looking for though.

Answer (score -1):

You can configure it by groupPadding
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.groupPadding

Comment: the question doesn't appear to be about the padding at all, it's about having each series grouped with itself, and not the default grouping that is used.